# How Can I Query 2 Tables And Multiple Columns?

Tags: php, mysql

I researched this a bit already and all my attempts have come up short so far.  I am trying to perform a mysql query in my php script that deals with multiple tables.

Here is what the tables look like:

> **TABLE 1**
>
> name
>
> **TABLE 2**
>
> Product (name)
>
> Inventory
>
> CatID
>
> ProductID
>
> **TABLE 3**
>
> product_url

"name" (Table 1) must be the sane as "Product" (Table 2). Next, "Inventory" (table 2) must be = to "Y".  Lastly, "CatID" must be = "2".

My attempt looked somewhat like this:

```
SELECT 1.name, 2.Product, 2.Inventory, 2.CatID
FROM table1 1, table2 2 
WHERE 2.Inventory = 'Y'
  AND 1.name = 2.Product
  AND 2.CatID = '2'
```

From the results, I would be looking to get more information from the table such as product description, etc which would be in table1 and table2... I have never joined or queried 2 (or more) tables before.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please accept answers to some of your earlier questions. You'll get swifter help.

Comment: If `t2.Product = t1.Name` and Name is the only column in t1, you have no need to JOIN.

Comment: You may want to read up about database normalization before designing your database. It will save you many headaches later on.

Comment: I hear you on that one... These are existing tables unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT table1.Name, table2.Product, tabl2.Inventory, table2.CatID
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.Name = table2.Product 
WHERE table2.CatID = '2'
```

Comment: I tried this and even added the "e" missing in tabl2.Inventory... It's still not working.  

$query = (" SELECT table1.Name, table2.Product, table2.Inventory, table2.CatID
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.Name = table2.Product AND table2.CatID = '2' ");
while($test = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
echo $test['name'];
}

Comment: The CatID = '2' should be in the WHERE clause, not the from.  Typo on my part in the original post.  The edited query is a valid query though assuming that the database is set up properly and you are successfully passing the values over from the php code.  You may get more values than you anticipate depending on the structure of the tables and your primary/foreign keys, but we would need more information to know that...

Comment: $test['name'] should be $test['table1.name'];

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.name, t2.Product, t2.Inventory, t2.CatID, t2.ProductID
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.Product = t1.name
WHERE t2.Inventory = 'Y' AND t2.CatID = 2
```

I'm sorry to say that the database you have to work with was very poorly designed.  If the query I gave you doesn't work, then make sure you have data in the tables that actually meets the criteria you're looking for.

Also remember that when you're accessing these fields in PHP, capitalization matters.  You need to do something like this:

```
<?php

$q = QUERY FROM ABOVE
$r = mysql_query($q);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)) {
    $name = $row["name"];
    $product = $row["Product"];
    $inventory = $row["Inventory"];
    $catid = $row["CatID"];
    $productid = $row["ProductID"];
}

?>
```